# using postifx as backend for messaging system in django?

Tags: python, django, postfix-mta

I am creating the project in which user will have ability to communicate with each other via messages.

I came up with an idea to try implement it using postfix and mails instead of writing models, and then querying db etc. The email on server will be not send anyway outside only inside server, and python/django will read them for displaying it in appropriate view for appropriate user.

**QUESTION:**
I would like to know what risks, security vulnerabilities or other problem can such design cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need full SMTP support (i.e. proper email between servers), there no point in using postfix.

Take a look at the [Django messaging framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/), it suits your needs much more than making a clumsy integration with postfix.

Alternatively, a Django model-based approach seems like a very good way to implement this, not sure why you're skeptical about it.